# Avoid CentOS 7 upgrade via yum?

Tags: centos, yum, upgrade

I help manage a small production server. The server runs a downlevel version of CentOS. CentOS recently announced [Release for CentOS Linux 7 (1511) on x86_64](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2015-December/021518.html).

Running *`yum update`* picked up the release and offered 400+ packages upgrades. We would like to prohibit the upgrade at the moment on the production server.

We are most concerned about an accidental upgrade, like a script using *`-y`*. We still want to receive updates for the older version of CentOS; we just don't want the OS upgrade.

How can we configure yum to avoid the CentOS 7 upgrade?

---

Here's what it looks like when we run *`yum update`*:

```
$ sudo yum update
[sudo] password for xxxxxxxx: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.hostduplex.com
 * epel: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * extras: mirror.hostduplex.com
 * updates: mirror.hostduplex.com
Resolving Dependencies
...
Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install    2 Packages (+6 Dependent packages)
Upgrade  412 Packages

Total download size: 374 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

---

Here is our `yum.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/yum.conf
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=23&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release
```

Here is the section in the manual covering the configuration: [12.4. Configuring yum](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-yum-yumconf.html). But its not obvious to me how to prohibit the upgrade.

Comment: I have to admit I'm not that firm with current CentOS, is 1511 basically the same as RHEL 7.2 ? The announcement says "third major release for CentOS 7" and "derived from RHEL 7.2" so what is it now? Centos 7.2 or 7.3 ? Just curious ...

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be the same question as [How do I keep Centos at version 6.3?](https://serverfault.com/questions/490330/how-do-i-keep-centos-at-version-6-3) and the second answer that might help you achieve what you want: https://serverfault.com/a/500606

Something like this might work:
`yum --releasever=7.0 update`
You may have to adapt as I'm not sure what `releasever` your currently installed CentOS uses, maybe you also need to use 7.1.
The latter answers to [Yum: How can I view variables like $releasever, $basearch & $YUM0?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19701/yum-how-can-i-view-variables-like-releasever-basearch-yum0) should help you with that.

Although another source mentions that this might still draw updates from later point releases, see http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/rhel-yum-update-without-migrating-to-point-releases-4175456496/

FWIW, this was also already asked the same way as [How can I keep the RHEL version static (e.g. RHEL 5.1)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/70021/how-can-i-keep-the-rhel-version-static-e-g-rhel-5-1) but I don't think that solution will work as cleanly as the above or if it will work at all.

---

Comment: Thanks doktor5000. If it can be done, then I think this probably holds the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve your goal.

The easiest is to add `exclude=*` in your  `/etc/yum.conf` file.

The second is to disable all the repositories. For each definition of repository into in /etc/yum.repos.d/ add a line `enabled=0`, ie (CentOS-Base.repo):

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=0
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... It seems like `exclude=*` is easiest, but would it prohibit updates to installed packages?

Comment: Yes, prohibit also that a new package will be installed.