# linux + yum + how to print the yum variables by yum command

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, repository

I just Wondering if we can print the yum parameters without to view the yum configuration files ( by more or cat or vi ... etc)

for example

I configured the variable , in  /etc/yum.conf

```
  installonly_limit = 2
```

in order to remove the oldest kernel every time a new kernel is installed

can yum print the variables values as installonly_limit ?

Comment: I don't think so. You would do the best with `sed` or similar tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, yum can do that, although you might need the valuable `yum-utils` package installed.

You can either use `yum-debug-dump` to print all the internal variables, or you can use a small python script to only print what you need specifically (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19701/yum-how-can-i-view-variables-like-releasever-basearch-yum0) at the link below for that) or you can try with `yum-config-manager` to see if it shows what you need.

More details are provided in the existing question [Yum: How can I view variables like $releasever, $basearch & $YUM0?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19701/yum-how-can-i-view-variables-like-releasever-basearch-yum0)